# How to figure out what app is beeping at me?

Tags: macos, audio, notifications

Every now and then, on my Mac, I hear a bell.  I have no idea what app it is, or why it's beeping at me.

My first thought was that it's coming from the Notification System in OS X 10.8 (I never heard such a thing on 10.7), but I turned off the sound notifications for every app listed in the Notification preferences.

Is there any way to tell what app is doing this to me?

UPDATE: I think it might have been Mail -- it has its own sound notification preferences, apparently.  But I'm not certain, and the question as written still stands: how do you know where sound comes from?

Comment: Mail was the first thing that I thought of - but since you checked NC, I didn't mention it. It may have something to do with the difference between VIP email alerts (which would be Notification Center), and just an "noise" that indicates that you have new mail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an easy, general way to determine exactly what process is making a sound, but if I had to track it down, I'd use an "audio router" (E.G., http://jackosx.com/about.html) and reroute each process/application one at a time until I figured out which was causing the sound.